# Sum the many to one elements in subquery before joining to main table

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I need to sum all values that belong to an ID within a subquery before I use the result of that subquery to join to my main table. For example:

```
Table A
ID   |   Site
1    |   TX
2    |   NY

Table B
ID  |  Cost
1   |   10
1   |   2
1   |   8
2   |   3
2   |   7

Select A.Site, B.Cost
from A 
Left join (select distinct ID, Cost from B) as B
on A.ID = B.ID
Group by A.Site;
```

The result for this table is:

```
Site   |   Cost
TX     |    10
NY     |    3
```

It should be

```
Site   |   Cost
TX     |    20
NY     |    10
```

It seems that my subquery is not pulling all the cost that belong to each Distinct B.ID - as a result my join only brings the first cost record instead of the sum of each cost record per B.ID

How can I sum all cost within the subquery before I join it to the main table? I need to use a subquery because my IDs are one to many, and my tables are huge so if I just join both tables the query takes for ever.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like this could be solved with a subquery

```
Select 
    A.Site, 
    (SELECT SUM(B.Cost) FROM B WHERE B.Id = A.Id) as `Cost`
FROM A;
```